# How to get google plus user wall feeds in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've successfully integrated Google plus SDK in my iOS app. Right now its getting all the info of the user and user wall feeds.But how to get all feeds attachment image.

**Code:**

```
 GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForActivitiesListWithUserId:@"me" collection:@"public"];

[[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] plusService]
  executeQuery:query
  completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLPlusActivityFeed *actFeed, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        for (GTLPlusActivity *activity in actFeed.items)
        {
            NSLog(@"name%@",activity.title);
            NSLog(@"name%@",activity.title);
        }
    }
}];
```